# Find a Injection from the set of all Ideals of $L/I$ to the set of ideals of $I$ where $L$ is a Lie-algebra and $I\subset L$ an ideal

Tags: ideals, lie-algebras

Since I am new to Lie-algebras and my algebra knowledges are a bit rusty. I am not sure how to approach this task. I got the definition, that $I$ is a Ideal, if $[x,y]$ for $x\in I$,$y\in L$. What do we know in general about ideals of the quotient $L/I$ and of ideals of ideals,rsp. $I$? How does a element of $L/I$ even look like (is it just like $x+i$ where $x\in L,i\in I$)? Is there even a way to count ideals given a finite field? I hope my questions are not that incomprehensible.

Comment: Formally, an element of $L/I$ is a subset of $L$ of the form $a+I=\{x \in L\ |\  x-a \in I\}$. Thus, given a subset $J \subseteq L/I$, you can see it naturally as $\tilde{J}$ a subset of $L$. And you can check that when $J$ is an ideal of $L/I$, then $\tilde{J}$ is an ideal of $L$.

Comment: @user1952009 thanks for your answer. Will I find the injection by checking that? Furthermore, is there a way to determine the ideals, respectively, is there a simple way to characterise them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, take $L$ be any non zero nilpotent Lie algebra (or any Lie algebra which has more than one ideal) and $I=\{0\}$ the zero ideal.

I believe you want to find an injection between the set of ideals of $L/I$ and the set of ideals of $L$ which contain $I$ in this case if $p:L\rightarrow L/I$ is the quotient map the map which associates to an ideal of $L/I$ its inverse image by $p$ realizes this injection.

Comment: Would it be true, if one had to find an injection from the set of all ideals of $L/I$ to the set of ideals of $L$? Is there maybe a common notation for the set of all ideals? Thank you

Comment: However, how can I know what the ideals of $L/I$ are? Is the quotient map given by $x \mapsto x+i$ where $i \in I$?